# i want to show the welcome.jsp is my initial page in the project but it not coming so any one find the mistakes and help me

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>mavenproject1</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### This is the controller class

```
 @Controller
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showFirstPage(){
    System.out.println("Hi Hello mallesh How are you..");
    ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("welcome");
    return model;
}
}
```

### This is the configuration class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.mycomany.mavenproject1.*"})
public class LoginApplicationConfig {
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
}
```

### This is the webApplicationInitializer class

```
public class WebAppApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { LoginApplicationConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
   return new String[] { "/" };  
}
```

}

### This is my welcome.jsp class

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Welcome To My Project...</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

it not show the welcome.page as first page whenever i run my project it shows resource not found

Comment: can you please add the web.xml file content in the question

Comment: Try replace `value = {"/"}` for `value = "/"`. And check you deployment directory is there `WEB-INF\welcome.jsp`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795055/i-want-to-show-the-welcome-jsp-is-my-initial-page-in-the-project-but-it-not-comi

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add the following code in the web.xml file.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: it is spring spring 4.x so i not use the web.xml

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer of Sachin Aryal, You can add more number of welcome pages.

`<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file> 
    <welcome-file>firstpage.html</welcome-file> 
    <welcome-file>first.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>`

The first available file will be taken as welcome file